# Android Patterns

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-actionbar

I'm want to improve the design of my app. Looking for some patterns, I've found http://www.androidpatterns.com.

For Action Bars pattern, I've found a perfect library (actionbarsherlock.com).

www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/action-bar

i.stack.imgur.com/xODIL.png

But there is a problem my app uses TAbActivy and this actionbarsherlock does't(because this library uses FragmentActivity and its imcompatible with Tabs) work with this, yet.

Now, I wanna apply this patterns. I wanna change Tabs for nice (beaty) buttons.

androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/segmented-control-2

androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/slideable-top-navigation

androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/segmented-control

Follow some actual screenshots of my app:

i.stack.imgur.com/lIfbg.png i.stack.imgur.com/4kMYe.png

**To apply this patterns and use actionbarsherlock, what is the best way?**

I've found it thow anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html . But I dint like graphs and it load all contect once. It doesnt works like a TabActivity (opens activity separately).

i.stack.imgur.com/y0lEV.png

Comment: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) supports tabs, on all supported versions of Android, according to the project site and its source code.

Comment: [Android Support Library, revision 18](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) has support for ActionBar from Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher

Comment: The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above. To improve your pattern you might take a look on this: https://github.com/snowdream/awesome-android There are powerful libraries you might use and improve your code!